# Creating class member functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, oop

I'm attempting to create a class member function for a class I've created. Currently the Class has a 2D array that's populated by reading text from a file.

What I'm then attempting to do is manipulate the array through the member functions to carry out different tasks (I'm creating a menu-driven program).

```
class Person
{
private: 
    string sname;
    string fname;
    string sex;
    string dob;
    string array[4][8];
public:
    Person();
    void getSex(); <-- This is where I'm struggling
};
```

From my main I have a switch case that I'm using to call the functions.

```
int main()
{
    switch (case)
    {
    case '1':
        Person();
        break;
    case '2':
        Person::getSex();
        break;
}
```

I then have the function that I've created below:

```
void getSex()
{
    for (int r = 0; (r < 4); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; (c < 2); c++) cout << array[x][y] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

However in the function I've created I'm getting an error on the array which says:

"a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object."

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong and please help me rectify it?

**Edit:**

So I now know I shouldn't use static and instead (as a minimum) should be using void (although having an actual return type would be better - but if I set the function to void my array becomes undefined?

Comment: why did you declare `getSex` as `static` ?

Comment: A get function returning `void` - what's the point? At a minimum, that's odd.

Comment: as @tobi303 said, you cannot use class member `array` in a `static` function. You need to either mark `array` `static` as well, or (this is most likely what you want to do) change the functions definition to `void getSex(); `

Comment: <joke mode on>English is not my mother tongue, but as far as I know,  "Sex" in English is not the same as "Gender", as (e.g.) in Italian. getSex seems a quite funny activity, but maybe you meant something else :P

Comment: You should decide what variables are you going to use in your loops: `r` or `x`, `c` or `y`?

Comment: Thank you everybody. So I've changed getSex from being static to Void, however I'm now confused as to how I can access the array I've created? Because now it's saying that array is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object."

That's for your array, which is not `static`, while `getSex()` is `static`. However does it make sense to mark that method as `static`? I mean every `Person` will have its sex (male of female).

---

PS: Usually getter functions return something, while your function has as return type `void`. I suspect you do that just for testing (since you print something).

Comment: Limiting sex to male or female doesn't quite cut it in the real world ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl I was thinking the same thing. The compiler never assumes gender.